# Nginx service stops every one hour

Tags: services, nginx

I have a DirectAdmin server configure with nginx service as reverse proxy.
Everything runs pretty good for several months and years.

Since yesterday, DirectAdmin send me each hour on the 17th minute an email that "The service 'nginx' on server XXX is currently down".

When I check it out it's seems that nginx running good (and maybe has restarted by DirectAdmin).

I check my Crontab and i can't find any task that run at this time. Also i couldn't find any error on nginx error_log related to this problem.

```
CentOS 5.9 (Final)
DirectAdmin 1.44.3 (Latest)
Nginx 1.1.10


Nginx configured with several Node.js instances and working as reverse proxy.
No changes made recently.
```

Any help?

Comment: Any log entry? You might need to go into more details e.g. which system your nginx is running on etc.

Comment: I add some details about my system. I already check the logs, anything specific?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the service running and there is no log correlating DirectAdmin assumption, I suppose it is wrong. You should also know whether DirectAdmin restart services on failed alive test.

Are you sure DirectAdmin way of 'pinging' nginx is right and working? Maybe DirectAdmin check for nginx running every **:17 and its test fails for another reason...

Blaming nginx with the current 'evidence' looks like bulling... Try to handle your setup/the tools you use.